# How to turn off invite person option in Jitsi Meet Activity in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm working on an android application in which I'm using Jitsi Meet API for video and conferencing but on the meeting page, there is an option to invite people which take to the browser and ask to download Jitsi meet app which I don't want to show in my app.
I want to ask is there any way I can hide that button.

```
URL serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
                        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder builder = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder();
                        builder.setServerURL(serverURL);
                        builder.setWelcomePageEnabled(false);
                        builder.setRoom(meetingRoom);
                        JitsiMeetActivity.launch(OutgoingMeetingActivity.this, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 3):

### **UPDATE**

Here are some more flags as of 2021 from [Jitsi docs](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/mobile-feature-flags)

---

you can use flags from Jitsi meet SDK.

```
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder builder =   new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
            .setServerURL(serverURL)
            .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
            .setFeatureFlag("chat.enabled",false)
            .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)
            .setVideoMuted(videoMuted)
            .setUserInfo(userInfo)
            .setSubject(toName)
            .setRoom(roomId)
            .build();
```

`setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)` is used to disable invite feature.

Also, you can find some useful flags from [Jitsi-Meet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/base/flags/constants.js)

Comment: how to remove the toolbar button ? I tried everything on your given link, but nothing work.

Comment: @ankalagba Do you want to remove one of mute, end conference, pause video buttons?

Comment: I want to remove the 3 dots button (the option button) that show the dialog. Is it possible to remove it ? Thanks for answers.

Comment: The only things that work in your given link are: `.setFeatureFlag("chat.enabled",false)
            .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)`. The others has no effect.

Comment: I think you need to remove it from [here](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/01c55bdb156e04a23a874a058e8463f7cedadac2/react/features/toolbox/components/native/Toolbox.js#L118) and re-build the SDK yourself and integrate it into your app.

Comment: You can see an image, I opend an issue here: https://community.jitsi.org/t/hide-more-setting-button-in-mobile-sdk-side/91220

Comment: "you need to remove it from here and re-build the SDK", Headeach I don't know nothing about react native. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled",false)`

This feature flag alone won't do it.
You have to check the react code to figure it out, as I did, to remove the invite button, you need to change the server file `interface-config.js` or `config.js`. Check either one of them. I forgot which one.

When you use the SDK, if you specify the server URL, the app loads the config from the web. This is how it works. If you use the Jitsi Meet original app for testing, without setting the server URL in settings, then it uses the config file from their server.

The first answer shouldn't be upvoted. It's not correct I think as of 2021.
I'm using branch `mobile-20.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

for remove from the screen, open native Toolbox.js file and comment this line;

```
 {/* additionalButtons.has('invite') && <InviteButton styles = { buttonStylesBorderless } /> */}
```